# Understanding the Expression of Expected Prediction Error (EPE) from "The Elements of Statistical Learning" (Page 26, Equation 2.27)

Tags: statistics, expected-value, linear-regression

The expression comes from **The Elements of Statistical Learning** p26(2.27).

Following picture is our tearcher's slide:[image]

I don't understand the red underlined. Isn't that the expectation of $\hat{y}_0$ is $f(x_0)$? I think: $E(\hat{y}_0)=E(x_0^T\hat{\beta})=x_0^T\beta=f(x_0)$.
So why $E_{\mathcal{T}}(f(x_0)-\hat{y_0})^2=Var_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y_0})+Bias^2(\hat{y}_0)$?
Isn't it only equals the Var? Why there is also a Bias.

Maybe a silly problem...But I feel so confused. I need your help!thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general the expression theyve written is correct, since the bias is not always $0$. But in this case (you can see on the next line) the bias is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think as the red write in the picture. $E_{\mathcal{T}}(f(x_0)-\hat{y_0})$ directly equals to $Var_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y_0})$... I don't understand why there is a Bias.

Comment: Because it depends on the method of determining $\hat \beta$. Let's say i propose a method where $\hat \beta$ is always $0$. Then the variance is 0, but the error is obviously large in the general case. Does that make it clear why you need a bias term?

Comment: If this still doesnt answer your question, try writing out $E_{\mathcal{T}}(f(x_0)-\hat{y_0})^2$ and $Var_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y_0})$, expand the values and see that they are not equal!

Comment: Now I see! I understand.Thank you very much